# Understanding scheduling of coroutine

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-coroutine, cppcoro

The scheduling of coroutine on execution context, as done e.g. through [lewissbaker/cppcoro/schedule_on](https://github.com/lewissbaker/cppcoro#schedule_on) puzzles me.

I think I understand the simpler case of executing regular (i.e. non-coroutine) code after co-awaiting a scheduler, such as [[ref](https://github.com/lewissbaker/cppcoro#static_thread_pool)]

```
cppcoro::task<std::string> do_something_on_threadpool(cppcoro::static_thread_pool& tp)
{
  // First schedule the coroutine onto the threadpool.
  co_await tp.schedule();

  // When it resumes, this coroutine is now running on the threadpool.
  do_something();
}
```

Which I can relate to the cppreference "switch_to_new_thread " example on the [coroutines page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines).

However, I cannot get my head around a code snippet like

```
cppcoro::task<std::string> do_something_on_threadpool(cppcoro::static_thread_pool& tp)
{
  // First schedule the coroutine onto the threadpool.
  co_await tp.schedule();

  co_await wait_for_something();

  do_something();
}
```

Which when I tested it worked as expected: `do_something()` was executed on the thread pool.

If I understand correctly, the coroutine is resumed on the thread before hitting `co_await wait_for_something();`. What happens then? Since the coroutine was resumed on  thread pool by a regular function, how can it `co_await`?

Comment: "*Since the coroutine was resumed on thread pool by a regular function, how can it `co_await`?*" I don't really understand what you mean by that. How a coroutine is resumed has nothing whatsoever to do with whether any subsequent `co_await` makes sense. Do you think a coroutine can only be resumed *once*? That'd be a pretty poor coroutine design.

Comment: I would basically like to understand how (i.e. through which mechanism) it is resumed after the thread executing it on the thread pool hits the `co_await` and suspends it? Is the coroutine handle posted to the scheduler again through `tp.schedule()`'s `await_suspend` method?

Comment: "*What happens then?*" What does `wait_for_something` return? What does that object's documentation say about its awaitable behavior?

Comment: In my test it was a `cppcoro::task<>` [[ref](https://github.com/lewissbaker/cppcoro#taskt)], but if you have the patience to explain the general case, that would be really great ... :) These coroutines are quite something!

Comment: @Tony the general case is that anything can happen. Something like 6 user-definable member functions are associated with `co_await wait_for_something();`, many of which are themselves potentially coroutines of different types

Comment: Ok! I suppose the use case as I am interested in is that of waiting for another thread to fulfill the request initiated by `wait_for_something`. So we could assume a `cppcoro::task<T>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that `wait_for_something` is also a `cppcoro::task` (or something who's promise type has `std::suspend_always initial_suspend()`), who's body doesn't do any thread switching.

`co_await wait_for_something();` does the following things:

- The coroutine state for `wait_for_something` is created (in a suspended state).

  - This corresponds to the `wait_for_something()`
- The `std::coroutine_handle` associated with `do_something_on_threadpool` is passed to the promise associated with `wait_for_something()` via the `await_suspend` member

  - It is up to the coroutine machinery of `wait_for_something` to put this somewhere, for it to be resumed when `wait_for_something` finishes. That resume will proceed on to `do_something()`
- `wait_for_something` is resumed

  - Those steps correspond to the `co_await`

Comment: Thanks! What happens to the thread calling `wait_for_something` though? Does it return and go back to the pool of available threads? What mechanism leads to `do_something` execution?

Comment: @Tony presumably `wait_for_something` (eventually) `co_return`s or finishes, and that  means the compiler generated `co_await promise.final_suspend()` resumes `do_something_on_threadpool`, which proceeds to `do_something();`

Comment: There's any number of things that you `await_suspend` on and then resume, who are responsible for calling `handle.resume()` at some point.

Comment: Assuming `wait_for_something` follows a similar pattern and is executed on a new thread. Do you mean that the thread which `co_return` from `wait_for_something` carries on to execute `do_something`?

Comment: @Tony yes. Specifically the thread that finishes the final_suspend

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot! Maybe you could add `do_something` to your reply? It is a bit surprising to me that `do_something` is not executed on the context passed to `do_something_on_threadpool`, and I suppose it could be as well to other coroutines newbies.

Comment: @Tony In many cases it will be. We have to allow for the possibility that `wait_for_something()` will switch threads because if it can't, why can `do_something_on_threadpool`?